# Doxycycline tablet to suspension?

Tags: cats, health

I took my cat to the vet yesterday and she prescribed *Doxycycline 100mm/ml Susp.  #6mls*. Unfortunately, the hospital that prescribed it doesn't sell it. I've called several other vets and they only sell the tablet form.

The only hospital vet that has the suspension is quite a long drive from where I live, and they only sell it if they prescribed it. Not only that, it's $25 + tax.

On the other other hand, every drugstore has this drug in tablet form.

Since I can only find the tablet, is it possible to give the cat the tablet or change the tablet to suspension?

Comment: I would call my vet and ask. They know why they prescribed it.

Comment: They prescribed it but they don't sell it. Why prescribe it if nobody has it?

Comment: I meant call your vet and ask whether the tablet would also work and if they can prescribe it.

Comment: do not give doxycycline tablets to your cat it is dangerous if the pill gets stuck it can be fatal,the medication comes with a lot of warnings on the label.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't change the medication without consulting your vet first, even if it seems to be the same active ingredient.

First, **ask a pharmacy if they can order the medicine as prescribed**. I don't know where you live, but where I'm from most pharmacies can order most prescriptions over night, including medication for animals. Exceptions apply to dangerous substances like cancer treatment and addictive substances.

If that still doesn't work, ask the vet to prescribe the tablets instead. If you call in advance and explain your problem, they might prepare the new prescription and you only have to retrieve it.